# Jquery val() won't work?

Tags: jquery

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    alert(this.val());
});
```

Why this won't work? 
What I want is that every time a radio button is selected, the page alerts its value.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Is the DOM ready when this is executed? We need to see the whole page with the HTML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you need to do this:

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

As @Eonasdan already said, you need to use `$(this).val()`.

The reason for this is that `this` points to the plain DOM element and `.val()` needs a jQuery object.

By the way, you **must** quote the attribute value in an attribute selector: `$("input[type='radio']")`

Comment: Although their documentation calls them "mandatory", the requirement for quotes is secretly true only for attribute values with spaces in them, and for jQuery 1.4.4+; versions before that work fine (most of the time). With that said, I **do** recommend *always* including quotes anyway.

Comment: I guess the quotes are only optional for space-less cases to avoid breaking legacy code and tons of older plugins. So just like you can write alphanumerical strings in PHP without quotes (yes, really! will throw a "treating constant as string" notice though) it's nothing you should do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'jQuerify' the `this` object:

Rather than `this.val()` it should be `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead:

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

You must wrap `this` in a jQuery object to use the .val() method.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery, functions you pass to it's API provide `this` as the DOM elements that matched your selector.  However, `this` is not a jQuery object, it is actually a plain of DOM element.  If you want to call jQuery methods on `this`, you need to wrap `this` in jQuery: `$(this)`.

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

And don't forget to cache it if you use it multiple times to avoid recreating the wrapper over and over.

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('omgitchanged');
    alert($this.val());
});
```